# Flex Image Source Server Side Flash and Air

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm trying to run my flex application in the air runtime instead of flash runtime. It seems to work perfectly except the images. Adobe Air runtime tries to load them. Is there a way  to  change the root adresses for Image to server side? If possible I'd like to use the same code for flash runtime and air runtime .. "single codebase ;-)"

```
var icon:Image = new Image();
icon.source = "images/test.png";
```

regards
cyrill

Comment: Did you include the assets when packaging your AIR app?

Comment: Nope .. i hoped i could the use the assets deployed on server side. I tried do include them in the project and then it works.. but as soon as i create the exe with the flashbuilder export tool I get a exception... well a not defined exception. I could find any log files according this error.

Comment: there are around 10000 images

Comment: If you use the images on the server, that means they won't show when the application has no internet connection. If the images aren't likely to change, I see no reason why you wouldn't package them.

Comment: If your app uses so many images, I guess they're small enough to embed them. They will take long to load even on good connection because of inevitable ping.

Comment: Is it a known issue that projects with a big amount images can't be exported to a exe file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I would simply package the assets into the AIR app. That way the relative paths would be valid both in the web app and the desktop app. However, since you pointed out in the comments that we're talking 10000 images you'll have to find another solution.

What you need is a variable that is configurable for each type of project. The final code to access your images should look like:

```
var icon:Image = new Image();
icon.source = rootUrl + "/images/test.png";
```

That `rootUrl` may be `""` for the web app, and `"http://www.mydomain.com"` for the desktop app. Or it could be the absolute path in both cases. It doesn't matter: we don't want to hardcode that URL into our application.

Create a .properties file (or XML, or JSON; whatever configuration file you like) that contains the value for `rootUrl` and read that into your application model. This configuration file can be packaged into the AIR app.

A .properties file will look like this:

```
#myapp.properties
rootUrl=http://www.mydomain.com
```

For reading the file, you *could* use AIR's file streaming capabilities, but I suggest you load it the old-fashioned way with a `URLLoader`: this way it'll work both in the web and the desktop app.

Comment: Thanks..  Just did that an it worked. :) .. I implemented some caching mechanism so it loads them only once.  Do you know if this is a known issue .. packaging air application that contains 10000 of images?

Comment: @CyrillZadra Sorry, don't know about that. You can try to find it for yourself in the [JIRA](https://bugs.adobe.com/flex/).